# React componentDidUpdate infinitive loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update a component whenever firestore updates its database but as soon as the component is mounted, componentDidUpdate starts running and goes into an infinite loop. Don't know what I'm doing wrong or how to structure my if statement.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  console.log('did mount');

  axios.get(url).then((r) => {
    let arr = [];
    arr.push({
      ['drop' + [i + 1]]: {
        status: r.data.documents[i].fields.status.stringValue,
      },
    });

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      newDat: arr,
    });
    console.log(this.state.newDat).catch((e) => console.log(e));
  });
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
  console.log('didUpdate');

  if (this.state.newDat && this.state.newDat !== prevState.newDat) {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((r) => {
        let arr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < r.data.documents.length; i++) {
          arr.push({
            ['item' + [i + 1]]: {
              status: r.data.documents[i].fields.status.stringValue,
            },
          });
        }
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          newDat: arr,
        });
      })

      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }
}
```

Comment: You're setting new state in `componentDidUpdate`, which will trigger a re-render and another call to `componentDidUpdate`, which will trigger a re-render and another call to `componentDidUpdate`, which will... It's not clear why the component updating means you should call the server again. The *component* updating doesn't mean Firebase updated. Can you give us more information about what should trigger the server call?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I'm trying to update a component that will change it's colour depending on the state of firestore. if the colour changes in Firestore, the component should also change it's colour.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is the fact that `this.state.newDat !== prevState.newDat` will always be satisfied since `newDat` is an array, and array comparison does not work like this. You should compare each value of the array to conclude if they are equal or not.

Comment: Hi, Should I first make the call to firebase and then check each individual item I get back from firebase?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve may require calling the Firebase API at regular intervals. [Here](https://sebhastian.com/setinterval-react-class/) is a tutorial for using `setInterval` in React class components, which may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting new state in `componentDidUpdate`, which will trigger a re-render and another call to `componentDidUpdate`, which will set new state again, which will trigger a re-render and another call to `componentDidUpdate`, which will set new state again, which will trigger a re-render and another call to `componentDidUpdate`, which will...

The reason for that is that no array is *equal to* (`===` / `==`) a different array, even if they have the same contents. So `this.state.newDat !== prevState.newDat` will always be true.

It isn't immediately obvious why the *component* updating means you should check for updates on the server again, but if you do need to do that, check that the arrays are *equivalent*. For instance, looking at the code a function something like this should check for differences:

```
// You'll probably need to adjust this!
function datDiffers(newDat, oldDat) {
    return (
        newDat.length !== oldDat.length ||
        newDat.some((newEntry, index) => {
            const oldEntry = oldDat[index];
            const key = `${item}${index + 1}`;
            return newEntry[key].status !== oldEntry[key].status;
        })
    );
}
```

Then the check in `componentDidUpdate` might be:

```
if (this.state.newDat && datDiffers(this.state.newDat, prevState.newDat)) {
```

But again, that's if it really makes sense to call the server when `newDat` changes contents, which it's hard to say it does without more context.

Comment: I'm trying to run that function but it says oldDat is null. Which in this case will be the prevState.newDat is null. I guess it's looking at the first time the array gets mounted

Comment: @CarlosCorrea - Just add a check for that.

Comment: I have. I added if(prevState.newDat !== null) at the beginning but the component still does not update automatically when firestore changes. Only when I reload the page

Comment: @CarlosCorrea - That's a *different* problem than the infinite update problem in the question. I could have sworn somewhere I commented asking whether Firestore provides some kind of event but I don't see it. That's what you'd want to use, rather than polling or similar. Good luck with it!